# XSS vulnerability in java

Tags: java

1. How to fix the below XSS vulnerability issue?

   How to secure my website from XSS vulnerability?

By adding a javascript in the URL of the website all the cookies values are being displayed.

below is a similar example of the URL which consists of a java script:

https://www.example.com/>< script>alert(document.cookie)< / script >&UserTarget=https://www.example.com/homepageredirect.jsp

To overcome this I added the below filer in obj.conf file in webserver 7.0:

---

```
Input fn="insert-filter"

method="POST"

filter="sed-request"

sed="s/(<|%3c)/\\< / gi"

sed="s/(>|%3e)/\\>/gi"
```

---

Ever after making these changes in the obj.conf , still the issue is not fixed. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

When you print your HTML just escape the special chars in the client side (or server-side, it depends for what you are going to print it) then you will be allowed to pass any input through without the need to use awkward regex or other kind of filter.

Example:
Let's say I have a variable that can receive a `<script>alert( document.cookie )</script>`, when I print I would do something like `<div> <%= escapeHTML( dangerousVariable ) %> </div>`.

Comment: I tried doing similar by adding that filter, but didn't work. Could you please check if any correction is needed in the above filter.

Comment: As I can see you are probably escaping those characters when the user inputs the data. This is not the safest way to avoid XSS. The true definitive way to avoid XSS injection is escaping those values when you print them to the html (when there is direct contact with html).

Comment: thanks a lot for ur response. The above filters if used in weblayers are breaking a few other applications.  So, could you please suggest some code level changes to fix this vulnerability.

Comment: Which frameworks are you using for client-side output? It is always wise to use a framework that controls this for you so you dont need to worry (if production is your must). You can use struts 2, JSF and others. I personally use struts 2 for my apps and jstl (JSP Standard Tag Library) for processes lacking a good support on struts (for the last you will need to pick a process of html escaping for each output coming from client input since struts already does that for you).

Answer (score 0):

[In this URL XSS Prevention Rules mention you can apply rules according to your requirement](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)